# Is separate memory allocated for functions and properties of an object?

Tags: c#, object, memory-management

This question is about .NET but I think it applies generally. When a new object is instantiated, are the functions in that object allocated memory too? Even if they are not called till a later point?

Put differently, will two classes with same member variables but one with more methods inside it occupy more memory at the time of instantiation?

Comment: Clearly, the member variables of each instance need to have different storage because they have different values, right? Do you think that the functions of each instance will be different? If so, why?

Comment: Not clear on when are functions allocated memory. At object instantiation or when called?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Object *instance* represents the state of the instance you allocated. So it holds a copy of all fields and properties you define inside corresponding *type*.

Methods that you define for a given type stay in another data structure, out from the instance itself, called *Method Table*.  Every single instance you allocate has a pointer inside that points to the its type's *Method Table*.

[image]

When you call a function on the method, it shifts its pointer necessary amount of addresses, pull the function, push on the stack all arguments available in memory, and calls the function.

More on this can read here: [Drill Into .NET Framework Internals to See How the CLR Creates Runtime Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx#S7)

Comment: The link contains the list of magazines only.

Comment: the above link is not working. after searching in web i found the it here. hope it will helpful -- http://blog.csdn.net/phiger/article/details/5566988

Answer (score 4):

> with same member variables but one with more methods inside it occupy more memory at the time of instantiation?

No. The space required for an instance depends only on the fields.

The methods require memory too but only one time per class. Like static fields. That memory is allocated when the class is loaded.

Answer (score 3):

Memory is allocated only for the properties not the methods (of an instance that is). A very small fraction of memory is allocated for the metadata of the method and it's code.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new instance of a class, the memory is allocated for that instance with all its members (as defined in the class). AS far as your question is concerned Method (function) local variables are only allocated when the method is invoked itself.

You can check the exact details of object creation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx)